# Reading a null byte with PySerial

Tags: python, pyserial

I send adc values from a PIC (microcontroller) to my PC from a com port. I use PySerial to read datas. But I have a problem when I try to read a null byte, it doesn't work.

```
if self.serial_com.inWaiting():
    val = self.serial_com.read()
else:
    print "no data"
```

When I send a null byte (0x00), he always displays "no data" so I can't read a null byte, why? I guess a null byte is not a data?

I'm using Python 2.7.9 and PySerial 2.7 on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PySerial documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial.html):

> The port is set up for binary transmission. No NULL byte stripping,
>   CR-LF translation etc. (which are many times enabled for POSIX.) This
>   makes this module universally useful.

I would check the transmission routines at the other end. Are you using a string send routine? (in that case, the routine stops before the `null`. You have to use a character by character send routine which is transparent for special values. Such as `write` if you are working in C)

Comment: In function read() from pyserial, it returns a bytes(data) and bytes = str. So maybe it's normal if I can't read null byte because read() return a "str" and not a real byte

Comment: Finally it works, it was a mistake in my C code with the PIC sorry. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jcoppens for you answer,
To send values from the microcontroller (in C) : firstly I split my adc value into 2 bytes (because it's 16 bits value), for example :

```
short int Value = 512;
char value_tab[2];
char* ConvertValue = value_tab;
*ConvertValue++ = Value & 0x00ff; // lower byte
*ConvertValue++ = ((Value & 0xff00) >> 8); // upper byte
```

And I send the value_tab with functions provide by Microchip ( putUSBUSART(char *data, BYTE  length) and CDCTxService() ). You can see these functions here :[description code](https://github.com/tkrworks/PICratchBOX_OSC.X/blob/master/USB/usb_function_cdc.c)

I tried to send a null byte with a rs232 terminal and it displays something, so I don't know why pyserial can't read it.